# At a high level what are the differences in laws in Canada that make guns more restricted than in the US?

Tags: united-states, canada, is-x-legal

What laws make it so that guns are less used in Canada than certain US states?

In both places a person is allowed to keep a gun with them in their home. Hypothetically they can use the gun in appropriate places (such as a shooting range) so what's to stop them from carrying it around and if question say they are just on their way to the range.

In Canada are you not allowed to use a gun even for self defense?

Answer (score 2):

### At a “high level”, the US Constitution guarantees a right to bear arms; no other nation’s does that

This means that any restrictions that the Federal or State governments wish to place on armaments are subject to [strict scrutiny](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_scrutiny). The government has to demonstrate in court that the law or regulation is necessary to achieve a "compelling state interest".

In every other nation on Earth, if a government wants to ban or restrict a weapon, they can. In most places, the elected representatives of the people have decided that allowing children and mentally ill  people to have automatic weapons on the street is a bad idea. Most of their constituents agree.

Comment: So in general children in the US are allowed to use guns? For example was it not a crime that the 17 year old Kyle Rittenhouse had a rifle?

Comment: @jumpjump It varies by locality, type of gun, and whether or not there is parental supervision.  The age limit in Rittenhouse's case, i.e. a long-barreled rifle in Wisconsin with no supervision, is 16.  Kyle was 17 at the time.

Comment: "no other nation’s does that" Czech Republic comes pretty close.

Comment: Agree that it should be strict scrutiny. The best precedent we have is Heller where intermediate scrutiny was used, but the door was left open to decideing what it really should be. There was a whole discussion about it since it apparently wasnt obviously strict scrutiny.